# Setting the favicon for all pages

Tags: html, wamp, favicon

Following code is for displaying favicon:

```html
<head>
    <title><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /></title>
</head>
```

Path for my image is: `wamp/www/widget_corp/favicon.ico`.

The URL for page was: `localhost/widget_corp/pat_apt.php`.

Problem is: I cannot display favicon. Can anyone tell me why? Also, suggest me the way to display favicon for all pages. I went through some forums they suggested to edit the config file. Is that true?
I am using **WAMP Server 2.4**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't embed your favicon code in title tags. **That's why you can't see it.**

To include same code in various pages, create a php file to contain your head information:

**header.php**

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Then call it between head tags of all of your pages:

```
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
  <? require_once 'header.php'; ?>
</head>
```

Comment: my header.php is in includes folder. I pasted favicon over there and modified the file to set the link however, I did not get the image?

Comment: If your header.php is in includes folder, you should try to fetch it from parent folder: `<link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="../widget_corp/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

you should put only your page's title text in `<title>`.